# How to convert this on to rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROFILES
WHERE last_name = 'aiu' AND first_name ='david'
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, middle_name, zip_code, street
```

Code:

```
Profile.all(:conditions => ["first_name = ?  OR last_name = ?",  params[:first_name], params[:last_name]], :group => "first_name, last_name, middle_name, zip_code" )
```

is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct all except in the query you have `last_name = 'aiu' AND first_name ='david'` and in rails `first_name = ? OR last_name = ?`.  

Are you using rails 2.3?

Answer (score 2):

You can verify it using [to_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql):

```
Profile.all(:conditions => ["first_name = ?  OR last_name = ?",  params[:first_name], params[:last_name]], :group => "first_name, last_name, middle_name, zip_code" ).to_sql
```